# why the element are't exactly in the center?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have a list of urls in `ul` element and I want the list in one row. I've tried [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6960714/center-div-and-display-on-same-line) to place them in the center of the page but they are not exactly in the center.

This is the HTML code

```
<ul id="links">
    <li class="inner-li"> <a href="about">about</a>

    </li>
    <li class="inner-li"> <a href="http://ahmadalli.net/projects">projects</a>

    </li>
    <li class="inner-li"> <a href="http://photo.ahmadalli.net">photoblog</a>

    </li>
    <li class="inner-li"> <a href="music">music</a>

    </li>
</ul>
```

and this is the style that I've tried

```
.inner-li {
    font-size: 1.25em;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 1em;
    list-style-type: none;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 21em) {
    #links {
        width: 21em;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
}
```

and you can see it in [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aELdJ/3/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `display:table` and `padding:0` to `#links` like:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 21em) {
    #links {
        display:table;
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 0;
    }
}
```

Also add

```
#links > li:first-child{
    margin:0;
}
```

cause first `li` element no need to has `margin-left`

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/aELdJ/8/)

Answer (score 3):

It's not centered because you've applied `margin-left` for the `<li>`'s.

```
.inner-li {
 font-size: 1.25em;
 float: left;
 margin-left: 1em; /* this */
 list-style-type: none;
}
```

Which will push the first `<li>` 1em away from the center.

You can achieve the same layout, centered by changing it to `padding: 0 .5em` instead.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aELdJ/9/)

Answer (score 0):

add this code your css file :

you should definition your menu width and other necessary codes.

```
#links {
    min-width: 100%;
}
```